# Redirect to next page and increment page id

Tags: php, hyperlink, auto-increment

I have a link scanner in php, after checking current URL that looks like this

```
mydomain.com/scanner.php?url=http://external-domain.com/index.php?article_id=15423
```

The script should go to the next url by incrementing the article_id value with 1.
I tried with a simple +, `page_id=15423+1` but it can't generate the next id which should be `15424`.

Any idea what should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:-

```
$value=current_value;
$value=$value+1;
header("location:http://mydomain.com/scanner.php?url=http://external-domain.com/index.php?article_id=" . $value);
```

Comment: Thank you, that gave me some ideas.